# When I click the collection view cell, the consecutive image is not displaying in the destination controller in ios 8

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview

I added the Segue from the collection view cell to the destination controller in UIstoryboard with the Identifier.I added the below code to Prepare for segue delegate.I also created a image view in destination controller and assigned a UIimage to the image view.

```
if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"third"])   

    {  
        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.collection indexPathForCell:_cell];
        fourViewController *imageDetailViewController = (fourViewController *)segue.destinationViewController;

        imageDetailViewController.pictures = [UIImage imageNamed:[self.list objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
        [imageDetailViewController setTitle:@"Four"];
        [self.collection deselectItemAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:NO];
}
```

**My Doubt**:

When I click the cell, the consecutive image is not displaying in the destination controller.why it happens? please help.

Comment: can any one help me?

Comment: Is `[UIImage imageNamed:[self.list objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]` nil? What's the code in `fourViewController` when you set the image ?

Comment: In fourth view controller I assigned the UIImage in .hfile and in .m file I did self.display.image=self.pictures; Where display- image view; pictures- UIimage.

Comment: Is `self.display` nil  when you try to set the image? If you set instead like this: `imageDetailViewController.pictures = [UIImage imageName:@"AnImageFromYourBundle"]`, where `AnImageFromYourBundle` is a valid image. Does it works?

Comment: If I click the cell, some other image in cell is displaying.I have other doubt, Is it necessary to add performSegueWithIdentifier in the did select row in the collection view?

Comment: Wait. Is the shown code even called? Is the value of `indexPath` correct?

Comment: Ya, tried with the above code I posted, as I said when i click the cell some other image in the cell displays in the destination controller.Ya the value of the indexpath is correct.

Comment: The problem is solved.Thanks for ur help.Is it necessary to add performSegueWithIdentifier in the did select row in the collection view?